# Is self-similarity a form of symmetry, is it the other way around, or is it something else?

Tags: soft-question, symmetry

I'm aware that self-similarity is a form of symmetry, however I'm interested in getting a more in depth explanation of the relationship.

Could you consider symmetry to be a form of self-similarity?

(Yes, the two definitions are nearly equivalent)

What's the difference between self-similarity and symmetry?

(Symmetry can refer to any preserved property while self-similarity refers to the whole being encoded in the fundamentals)

(1) things in parentheses are my guesses at the answer

I'm interested in a compare/contrast similar to the above so that I can better distinguish self-similarity from symmetry.

Comment: Usually a symmetry of a geometrical object is an isometry (i.e. an automorphism of Euclidean space) that sends the object to itself. One may wish to extend this definition to include other kinds of transformations, and with a bit of handwaving one may even [apply it to fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(geometry)#Scale_symmetry_and_fractals). I wouldn't think of symmetry and self-similarity as equivalent concepts, though. At best one could say that self-similarity is a special kind of symmetry.